# Use JavaScript to continously add number to itself

Tags: javascript, count

I am new to jQuery and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction regarding the following:

I have a number (`0.085`) and I am trying to figure out how, starting at `0` I can continuously add `0.085` to itself every second ie:

```
0, 0.085, 0.17, 0.255, 0.34 - etc.
```

I eventually would like to animate this so that the numbers look like the second/milliseconds of a stopwatch and actually count to the number. So if anyone knows how best to go about this then that would also be great.

Comment: Look for setInterval. But you don't need jQuery fo that, only JavaScript.

Comment: what kind of animation u need ?

Comment: Even though someone already answered, you should, in futur question, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval()`:

```
var count = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    count += 0.085;
    // update the UI as needed here...
}, 1000); // 1000ms = 1 second
```